# Display many plots 4x2

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Hello I have this code in Python :

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as plt

t = np.arange(0.0, 1.0, 0.01)
s = np.sin(2*2*np.pi*t)
fig, (ax, ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4, ax5, ax6, ax7) = plt.subplots(8,1)

ax.plot(t, s, 'o', color = "red")
ax1.plot(t, s, 'o', color = "red")
ax2.plot(t, s, 'o', color = "red")
ax3.plot(t, s, 'o', color = "red")
ax4.plot(t, s, 'o', color = "red")
ax5.plot(t, s, 'o', color = "red")
ax6.plot(t, s, 'o', color = "red")
ax7.plot(t, s, 'o', color = "red")

plt.axis([0, 1, -1, 1])
plt.show()
```

Everything works but I just want to have my plot of the form 4x2 and not 8x1 I try to replace `plt.subplots(8,1)` by `plt.subplots(4,2)` but I get `ValueError: need more than 4 values to unpack`

How can I do to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 2):

When you do `plt.subplots(4,2)`, you don't get a flat list of axes. If you do:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(4,2)
print(axes)
```

You'll get the following:

```
[[<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x00000000050CCBA8>
  <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x00000000059A0F60>]
 [<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x0000000005A24A58>
  <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x0000000005A896A0>]
 [<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x0000000005AC37B8>
  <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x0000000005B4EFD0>]
 [<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x0000000005B5FF60>
  <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x0000000005C18D30>]]
```

i.e. a list, where each element corresponds to one row of subplots. As such, if you do:

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as plt

t = np.arange(0.0, 1.0, 0.01)
s = np.sin(2*2*np.pi*t)
fig, axes = plt.subplots(4,2)

axes[0][0].plot(t, s, 'o', color = "red")
axes[0][1].plot(t, s, 'o', color = "red")
axes[1][0].plot(t, s, 'o', color = "red")
axes[1][1].plot(t, s, 'o', color = "red")
axes[2][0].plot(t, s, 'o', color = "red")
axes[2][1].plot(t, s, 'o', color = "red")
axes[3][0].plot(t, s, 'o', color = "red")
axes[3][1].plot(t, s, 'o', color = "red")

plt.axis([0, 1, -1, 1])
plt.show()
```

You'll get 4x2 as desired:
[image]